# Solve simple equations with unknown value in right side

Tags: r, function, equation

I want to find the x values in equation y = 2*x+100 when y varies from 200 to 250. I have the F1 function but it does not work.
I don't want to change the structure of equation to (y-100)/2 as the main equation is too complex.
any help would be appreciated.

```
F1 <- function(y){
  y = 2*x+100
  return(x)
}

F1(200:250)
```

Comment: `function(y)` but `return(x)`, and `x` isn't assigned anywhere. I'm guessing you want `return((y - 100)/2)`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to change the equation structure because it is a complex equation with lots of variables @diomedesdata

Comment: @Natalia If your real question involves a fundamentally different equation then your question is somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `uniroot()` to search for the root of a function.

```r
F1 <- function(x, y) {
  2 * x + 100 - y
}

sapply(200:250, \(y) uniroot(F1, c(0, 1), y = y, extendInt = "yes")$root)

#  [1] 50.0 50.5 51.0 51.5 52.0 52.5 53.0 53.5 54.0 54.5 55.0 55.5 56.0 56.5 57.0 57.5 58.0
# [18] 58.5 59.0 59.5 60.0 60.5 61.0 61.5 62.0 62.5 63.0 63.5 64.0 64.5 65.0 65.5 66.0 66.5
# [35] 67.0 67.5 68.0 68.5 69.0 69.5 70.0 70.5 71.0 71.5 72.0 72.5 73.0 73.5 74.0 74.5 75.0
```

Answer (score 3):

By simply rearranging the formula `y = 2 * x + 100` to solve for x, we have `x = (y - 100)/2`, so you could do:

```r
 F1 <- function(y) (y - 100)/2 

F1(200:250)
#>  [1] 50.0 50.5 51.0 51.5 52.0 52.5 53.0 53.5 54.0 54.5 55.0 55.5 56.0
#> [14] 56.5 57.0 57.5 58.0 58.5 59.0 59.5 60.0 60.5 61.0 61.5 62.0 62.5
#> [27] 63.0 63.5 64.0 64.5 65.0 65.5 66.0 66.5 67.0 67.5 68.0 68.5 69.0
#> [40] 69.5 70.0 70.5 71.0 71.5 72.0 72.5 73.0 73.5 74.0 74.5 75.0
```

And check this works by feeding these back in to our original equation, with the above numbers given as the values of x. This should return 200:250

```r
x <- F1(200:250)
 
2 * x + 100
#>  [1] 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215
#> [17] 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231
#> [33] 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247
#> [49] 248 249 250
```

For a more general solution, suppose we have your original function:

```r
F0 <- function(x) x * 2 + 100
```

We can define a solver that reverses the function to find the x value that gives a particular value of y by using `uniroot`.

```r
find_x_for_given_y <- function(y, func) {
  
  sapply(y, function(y_i) {
    uniroot(function(x) func(x) - y_i, c(-1e6, 1e6))$root
  })
}
```

So, to find the values which, when passed to `F0` give the values `200:250`, we can do:

```r
find_x_for_given_y(200:250, F0)
#>  [1] 50.0 50.5 51.0 51.5 52.0 52.5 53.0 53.5 54.0 54.5 55.0 55.5 56.0
#> [14] 56.5 57.0 57.5 58.0 58.5 59.0 59.5 60.0 60.5 61.0 61.5 62.0 62.5
#> [27] 63.0 63.5 64.0 64.5 65.0 65.5 66.0 66.5 67.0 67.5 68.0 68.5 69.0
#> [40] 69.5 70.0 70.5 71.0 71.5 72.0 72.5 73.0 73.5 74.0 74.5 75.0
```

Of course, this is the same as above, but is at least generalized to accept any function of one variable.

Comment: I was guessing the `uniroot` might be the thing the OP is really after and then you added it instantly, cheers! +1!